# Error 500 (Internal Server Error) during Pyrocms installation

Tags: php, pyrocms

I have Composer and XAMPP Server with `PHP 5.6` installed on `Windows 7`.

I'm following `Pyrocms` documentation here:
https://www.pyrocms.com/documentation/pyrocms/installation

Following the steps, I created a new pyrocms project inside htdocs/pyrocms and downloaded vendor packages with composer install

Now, while tring to open `localhost/pyrocms/public` in order to start Pyrocms installation, it gives me the following error:

[image: Pyrocms 500 Internal Server Error]

Apparently, laravel.log file shows the following errors: different line number every different time.

> [2016-09-11 15:14:11] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded' in F:\famp\htdocs\pyrocms\vendor\leafo\scssphp\src\Parser.php:898
>
> [2016-09-11 15:15:27] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded' in F:\famp\htdocs\pyrocms\vendor\oyejorge\less.php\lib\Less\Parser.php:2462
>
> [2016-09-11 15:16:15] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded' in F:\famp\htdocs\pyrocms\vendor\leafo\scssphp\src\Parser.php:844
>
> [2016-09-11 15:21:29] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded' in F:\famp\htdocs\pyrocms\vendor\leafo\scssphp\src\Parser.php:1354

What could be the possible cause for maximum time exceeded error?

Answer (score 1):

The error code 500 is a server error, so you should be able to find the reason of the failure in the server logs, somewhere like *\xampp\apache\logs*.

ETA: As you have edited your question, it's not rare that an installation script takes a long time. You should be able to find information about this in your CMS installation notes.

So, just for the installation time you can change your php.ini like this:

```
; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time = 300
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated the question with the log.

Comment: The logs say that the [max_execution_time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) of 30 seconds has been exceeded. In php.ini you can change that value to a greater value, like 300.